# Modifying .htaccess in Zend project

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I am creating a web project in Zend Framework

It contains only two controllers:

1. IndexController
2. AdminController

There isn't going be more than these 2 controllers. Here is the list of possible URLs and what I need them to transform in(or something similar to it):

> - Current --> **new**
> - BASE/index/action/parameter/value -> BASE/action/parameter/value
> - BASE/index/action -> BASE/action
> - BASE/admin/action AND BASE/admin/action/parameter/value :: URL

can stay like this,

It'd be easy with one controller, but I don't know where to start or how to figure it out with two. Somehow need to tell Zend which controller to use.

Current `.htaccess` is one generated by Zend:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

*(BASE = example.com)*

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: Have you tried how it works now? If i remember correctly when you give link like `/news` Zend will use default module (`Application`) and default controller (`IndexController`). So if you put your `newsAction` in `Application_IndexController` then it should open via link `/news`.

Comment: An error occurred 
Page not found.
Unfortunately, this doesn't work. However If I type only BASE, it uses `indexAction` in `IndexController` tho.

Comment: Use ZF's routing, don't modify the htaccess file.

Comment: @TimFountain thank you very much! had no clue about such option before. i guess this one is solved then with:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing.html